# calculate distance between rectangle face and edge screen

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying real time recognition faces and I found two files that python open source execution succeeded. The first file creates multi folders where folders' names are in a database that the second file depend on it. When I run the second file it take folders' names as database and it draws rectangle about faces. If the face is in database, it write folder name in a rectangle. If the face is not recognized, it writes "unknown" in rectangle.

I am not so strong in python so I want help you to add small changes on second file:

After recognition, the faces I need to show a message for user to enter "name", which will be found in database. After user enters their "name", the program should draw a rectangle only on this face, and create two variables. The first variable continues store distance between left rectangle edge and left screen edge. The second variable continues store distance between right rectangle edge and right screen edge. How can I do that?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The second file is:

Answer (score 0):

The `(x, y, w, h)` from each face corresponds to the `(x, y)` coordinates where the rectangle starts inside the whole `frame` picture; and `(w, h)` are the width and height of the rectangle, so the left and right distances you are looking for could be computed as

```
if prediction[1] < 500:
    x_left = x
    x_right = width - w - x
    ...
```

Where `width` referes to the `frame` picture as well.

**Edit**

If you need to compare the input name with the face names in database you can do:

```
name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
if name == face_name:
    ...
```

The `raw_input` will let the user introduce its name and store it in variable `name`, then you can check if it is in database.

Hope this helped!

Comment: yes that very important. but  i need user enter string "name" and my program draw rectangle only on this face that has name

Comment: @ ebeneditos 
 we need from user enter "name " and store that name in variable, now
 after condition "if prediction[1] < 500: cv2....." we must test if the name entrance from user equal the the face's name

Comment: What variable is the face name?